# If $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, show that there exists a closed set $F$ with $F \subset E$ and $m(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Just having trouble with this problem. First, it says to prove that if $E$ is Lebesgue Measurable, and $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, then there is an open $O$ such that $E \subset O$ and $m(O\setminus E)<\epsilon$. Now for this part, since $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, I was able to take the definition of being Lebesgue outer measurable (the infimum of open coverings of $E$) and easily construct $O$ from that, and it works out.

But now I want to show that there is an $F$ closed with $F \subset E$ and $M(E\setminus F)<\epsilon$. The problem is, I can't figure out how to construct this $F$! The idea seems obvious intuitively, but I feel like I am given no tools for constructing a closed subset of an arbitrary set that satisfies these conditions. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Think about complements.

Comment: Someone else I know told me this same advice, but I wasn't sure how to proceed. What do you mean?

Comment: @KirstenJanowicz I think you cannot delete since there's an answer. This prevents, for example, someone from getting an answer to his/her homework and then hiding the evidence.

Comment: You cannot delete your post because of two reasons: (1) There exists an upvoted answer, attempted vandalism will not remove the upvotes; (2) your user is unregistered, and unregistered users cannot delete their posts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I wonder why Kirsten wants to delete the question and answer so badly.

Answer (score 26):

If $E$ is measurable, then its complement $E^\complement$ is also measurable and we can find an open set $W$ so that $E^\complement \subset W$ and $m(W - E^\complement) < \varepsilon$. Let $F = W^\complement$ be a closed set. Since $E^\complement \subset W$, we have $F \subset E$. Moreover, $W-E^\complement = E-F$. Hence $m(E-F) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: I know it's super, late, but I couldn't see how $W-E^\complement = E-F$? @AymanHourieh Could you explain that, please?

Comment: @falamiw $W - E^\complement = W \cap E = E - W^\complement = E - F$.